# How to access a database handle in a PHP page responding only to Ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I have two files for my website: search_team.php and returnPossibleTeams.php. search_team is a mainly HTML page, that allows the user to type in the name of a team. Whenever `onKeyUp` is triggered, a JavaScript function is called which performs a GET request to returnPossibleTeams.php with AJAX. returnPossibleTeams.php needs to perform a query on a database and then return all the possible results.

---

search_team.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function showTeams(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("teamResults").innerHTML = "<br /><hr />Start typing the name of a team to search<br /><hr />";
            return;
        } else {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("teamResults").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "functions/returnPossibleTeams.php?q=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }

</script>

<div id="main">

    <br /><br />

    <!-- Search for a team with it's name or ID -->

    <div class="title">
        Search for a Team
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center;">

        <br />Enter the target team's name their TFConnections team page.<br /><br />
        From there, you can request an invite, view all of their rankings and members, and even
        <i>challenge</i> them (if you're in a team of your own).<br />You can also view information
        about possible upcoming events and other details they've set up!<br /><br />

        <input placeholder="Team Name" onkeyup="showTeams(this.value);" type="text" name="searchterms">

        <div id="teamResults">
            <hr />Start typing the name of a team to search<br /><hr />
        </div>

        <br />

    </div>

</div>
```

It should be noted that this page includes header.php, which creates a PDO MySQL database connection and stores that handle in `$db`.

---

returnPossibleTeams.php

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['q'])) {

        try {
            $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `teams` WHERE `Team Name` LIKE %:teamname%");
            $result = $statement->execute(array('teamname' => $_GET['q']));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "An error has occured.";
        }

        echo $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['Team Name'];
    }

?>
```

---

The problem I am having here is that returnPossibleTeams.php cannot access the `$db` database handle, as it's been established in a file included at the start of search_team.php. The simplest way around this problem of the missing recourse would be to create a new database connection at the start of returnPossibleTeams.php, but that would be extremely inefficient, as it would be creating a new database connection each time the user pressed a key! What's the best way around this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can put it in a condition.

```
if(!isset($db)) {
   //Here you have two choices either just connect to the database or require the fb connection file. Either way you need to connect to the database. 
}
```

This way if it is already set it won't create a new connection.

EDIT: I do however think that PHP will establish a new connection on each call anyway because it's how PHP works. Once the script finishes running and returns your data it ends which shuts done the database connection.

Comment: `$db` will never be set.

Comment: How do you mean it will never be set?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can be more clear... `$db` will never be set because it's a seperate file to where the the database handle is been created.

Comment: Oh I see what your saying that's why I put the bit of code in there I will clarify that.